# Hola estoy intentando intento usar un condicional así como se ve en la imagen pero me arroja el resultado del if y el else

Tags: javascript

[image: Este es el codigo con el que estoy trabajando]

como hago para que al momento de ejecutar el código este solo me arroje el resultado de el if y no de ambos??

Comment: Por muy "bonita" que se vea la imagen, no es la forma de compartir código en este sitio. Por favor, coloca el código a texto, para quien te ayude pueda copiar el código y modificarlo sin problema. Stack Overflow tiene resaltado de sintaxis, e incluso snippets que se ejecutan en la página para javascript. Edita tu pregunta y coloca el código a texto.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 2):

En ese contexto puede que el map no sea la forma correcta de hacerlo, puesto que el map va recorrer todos los elementos del arreglo que tienes. Lo que puede estar pasando es que sí esté validando la condición del if en algunos elementos pero en otros no.
Te recomiendo que cambies la apreciación de la solución. Podrías intentar con un foreach, recorriendo los elementos de tu arreglo original y aplicando la validación.
Si requieres el o los índices que vas a eliminar, puedes agregar estos índices a un arreglo auxiliar cuando se cumpla la condición. A continuación te dejo un ejemplo:

```
let list = props.list;
let arrIndexesForDelete = [];
list.forEach((item) => {
   if(item.title === itemForDelete){
       arrIndexesForDelete.push(list.indexOf(item)); 
   }
});
```